# Is there any shortcoming of the Langevin equation which is solved by its generalization?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The ordinary Langevin equation describing the velocity $v(t)$ of a Brownian particle of mass $M$ in a fluid bath in equilibrium at a fixed temperature reads $$M\frac{dv}{dt}=-M\gamma v(t)+\zeta(t)+F_{\rm ext}(t).\tag{1}$$ This equation is often superseded by the generalized Langevin equation $$M\frac{dv}{dt}=-M\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}\alpha(t-t') v(t')dt'+\zeta(t)+F_{\rm ext}(t)\tag{2}$$ where $\zeta(t)$ is a delta-correlated stationary Gaussian process with zero-mean. With $\alpha(t-t')=\gamma\delta(t-t')$, Eq.$(2)$ reduces to the ordinary form given by Eq.$(1)$.

Is there any unphysical feature or serious shortcoming of Eq.$(1)$ which is taken care of in Eq.$(2)$? This could motivate the use of Eq.$(2)$ instead of Eq.$(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motivation for using the generalized Langevin equation with memory kernel $\alpha(t-t')$ is the desire to include so-called memory effects, in which the evolution of the quantity of interest depends on its past states.  This could be useful in a number of contexts - [this recent paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.103.022102) suggests that the dynamics of phase transitions could be understood in terms of the (generalized) Langevin dynamics of the order parameter, and for reference I believe [this 1961 paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.124.983) by Robert Zwanzig is the paper which first generalized the Langevin equation to include temporal non-locality.

[This thesis](https://digitalrepository.unm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1098&context=phyc_etds) (which, in the interest of full disclosure, I have only skimmed briefly) appears to address the generalized Langevin equation and some contexts in which it is useful for generalized Brownian motion.

Comment: Useful, thanks! Does the exclusion of the memory effect in Eq.$(1)$ lead it to display any physically unrealistic feature (in the Brownian motion problem itself)? @J.Murray

Comment: @SRS As an example I'm just pulling out of the air, the motion of the particle through the fluid creates a disturbance - a wake - which would affect its future motion.  Such an effect could be modeled by an appropriate memory kernel, at least as a coarse approximation.  The parameters and conditions under which this effect is actually *relevant* is a different question, to which I'm afraid I don't have a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer by @JMurray, but I would like to stress that Langevin equation (and more generally Brownian motion) is not a physical system, but a mathematical approach, applicable to a multitude of physical situations: chemical reactions, cold atoms, electrons in a metal, nanomechanical pendulums, etc. Claiming that for all these diverse systems the dissipation is always frequency independent and the noise is always white (gaussian and delta correlated) would be a very strong and likely incorrect claim. In fact, this is certainly incorrect at high frequencies.

Just to clarify: by *frequency-dependent dissipation* I mean that $\alpha(t)$ is not constant, as can be seen, if we Fourier (more precisely Laplace) transform the Langevin equation.

Note also that dissipation is a response of the bath, related to its correlation function via the fluctuation-dissipation theorem - which is more fundamental than Langevin equation. In many cases both are derived from the microscopic properties of the bath, rather than postulated ad-hoc, so there is no guarantee that they behave "nicely".